# Trouble creating transactions

Tags: transactions

Since yesterday (2021-04-04) I`m having problems sending transactions. Most of them fail without throwing any exceptions, it seems like they are just not being included to any blocks.

I have enough CPU (CPU used - 5.32 ms / 17.89 ms) and NET (NET used - 3.16 KB / 22.49 MB).

My code and full node are the same since june of 2020, nothing has changed.

Did anybody had some trouble like this or have any idea about what can be causing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help, and I found the problem.

I had the parameters `blocksBehind` with 3 blocks, and `expireSeconds` with 60 seconds, I solved by changing to 20 and 120, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide mode details?
What is the nodeos version you are using.
Are you using cleos to send the transactions or eosjs?
Can you try using cleos and provide the output for both failing without error and for the others (you say most of them are failing without error).

I had to post this as an answer because I do not have yet 50 points to be able to comment... that's weird, right? I understand there's the need to moderate the commenting but to have 50 points to be able to comment it seems to me a too high of a barrier. Cause the comments might just be like this one, to guide about what more info is needed.

Comment: I've updated the node today to the version v2.0.11, and I'm using eosjs to submit the transaction. I've also tried increasing the transaction expiration from 30 secs to 60 secs. None of those procedures helped, my transactions are still not being sent to the network. No error is thrown, and nothing related is showing in the node logs either.

Comment: I see you already found the culprit.
I am just adding more info here which is relevant for anybody that ends up here and has questions about transactions and how to verify if they make it into a block; here's a series of FAQs that might help, I encourage reading all transactions related ones:

https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/faq/index/#are-there-any-plans-to-include-transaction-failure-tracing-in-state-history-github-feature-request

Comment: That's great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The old system of staking for CPU has been deprecated - if you're using Anchor you don't need to worry about resources anyways. In the meantime, you can visit https://eospowerup.io/free to get a free PowerUp every 12 hours

[Forwarded from Joe Louis] ⚡️ (https://t.me/eosresourcemodel/6588) PowerUp FAQ ⚡️

= What is PowerUp? =

```
Block One: EOS PowerUp Model (https://eos.io/eos-public-blockchain/powerup-model/)
Block One: EOS PowerUp Model Explained (https://eos.io/news/eos-powerup-model-explained/)
CryptoWriter: PowerUp Feedback (https://www.voice.com/post/@scottowen/eoswriter-eos-resource-model-feedback-1-1602648978-1)
CryptoWriter: EOS Ready to PowerUp! (https://www.voice.com/post/@kenny/eos-is-getting-ready-to-powerup-1611013733-903562310)
Podcast: Coffee w/Greymass on PowerUp (https://podcast.greymass.com/episodes/eosio-resource-model-with-yves-la-rose)
PowerUp as Office Space Analogy (https://twitter.com/eosvibes_bp/status/1311280222671720454?s=21)
Technical Community Feedback (https://www.notion.so/rentbw-Discussion-Portal-a7c873e532b148889f25c52239a8746e)
More Technical Community Feedback (https://medium.com/@alohaeos/eos-rental-market-guide-and-opinion-3dbfeafbcdae)
```

= When is PowerUp? =

NOW, it was activated on EOS Feb-23-2021 (https://bloks.io/transaction/44457a41361bb7ceb5dbbada41884a719da41e24d5021fe79164ffd245de74e8).

= Who is PowerUp for? =

Anyone can use PowerUp to rent resources for 24 hour periods at a time, BUT average users (most of us) will more ideally use Wallets (https://t.me/EOSproject/1643467) and Resource Providers that simplify and package resources for their users. PowerUp's target audience is developers and power users first.

How do I earn from PowerUp? Hold REX tokens. REX tokens are an accounting artifact that keep track of how many EOS tokens you own in the resource pool.

If you already have REX tokens, you will automatically be earning from network activity (PowerUp fees, REX fees, Name bid fees, RAM fees).

If you don't have REX tokens, you can deposit your EOS into a REX portal and start earning.

= Where do I PowerUp? =

If you're sure you want to pay to rent resources, more and more PowerUp portals will come about. Here's one from Bloks (https://bloks.io/wallet/powerup).